# Given a matrix of basis transformation what is the algorithm to find $ker(T)$ and $im(T)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm given the following transformation matrix of the linear map $T:\mathbb R^4\to\mathbb R^3$:

[image]

Find  $\mathrm{ker}(T)$ and $\mathrm{im}(T)$

So I should probably get this matrix to $\mathrm{rref}$:

[image]

But then what ? Also, what does the $\mathrm{rref}$ mean for this matrix ?

Comment: $\mathrm{rref}$ means "reduced row echelon form"

Comment: @NasuSama Yes I know what the acronym mean, I ask what does it mean for the transformation matrix. What can be learned from it in this case ?

Comment: With what you have done so far, solve the rref as a homogenous system and find the solutions. Those solutions are the basis of Ker(T). For Im(T) take the column vectors of the starting matrix and reduce them to rref. Those vectors are a basis for Im(T). And remeberer dim(Ker(T)) +dim(Im(T)) = dim (A). Hope this helps , if not I'm terribly sorry.

Comment: Just as remark: $T_{B_1}^{B_2}$ is the matrix of your linear map described by the basis $B_1$ and $B_2$. The dimension of kern and image space does not depend on the basis choice. :-)

Comment: One cannot answer this question without knowing what $B_1,B_2$ are; at best the kernel can be expressed in terms of $B_1$ and the image in terms of $B_2$.

Comment: Also how can the title call this a matrix of basis transformation? Change of basis matrices are always square, and this one is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to think about it: when we row reduce a matrix, what we're doing is computing another matrix by matrix multiplication on the left by some invertible matrix.  That is starting with are matrix $A$, we have
$$
E\cdot A = E_n\cdots E_1 \cdot A = \pmatrix{1 & 0 & 6 & 6\\ 0 & 1 & -3/2 & -1\\ 0&0&0&0}
$$
Where each of $E_1,\dots,E_n$ is an elementary matrix.  Because $E$ is invertible, this product has the following essential property:

> For a vector $x$, $EAx = 0$ if and only if $Ax = 0$

We may deduce two things from the above: first, the kernel of $EA$ (the reduced matrix) is the same as the kernel as $A$ (it is easier, however, to directly find the kernel of $EA$, which is in reduced row echelon form).  Second, the image of $A$ is $E^{-1}$ applied to the vectors in the image of $EA$.  What this means is that the image of $A$ will be **the span of the columns in $A$ corresponding to the position of the pivots in rref matrix $EA$**.  So, in this example, the image of $A$ is the span of the vectors
$$
\pmatrix{1\\1\\2},\pmatrix{2\\4\\2}
$$
Since $EA$ has a pivot ("leading $1$") in its first column and in its second.

Let me know if there's anything here you'd like me to clarify.  Hope that helps.

---

#### Elaboration regarding the image of $A$:

The definition of the image of $A$ is the set of all vectors $v$ for which $v = Ax$ for some vector $x$ in the domain of $A$.  The image of any matrix $A$ will necessarily be the span of all of its column vectors.  So, in this case, the Image of $A$ will be the span of the vectors
$$
\pmatrix{1\\1\\2},\pmatrix{2\\4\\2}, \pmatrix{3\\0\\9}, \pmatrix{4\\2\\10}
$$
The reason that this is the case is that we can, using matrix multiplication, write
$$
A \cdot \pmatrix{a\\b\\c\\d} = 
a\pmatrix{1\\1\\2} + b\pmatrix{2\\4\\2} + c\pmatrix{3\\0\\9} + d\pmatrix{4\\2\\10}
$$
While we can describe any image in these terms, it is not generally ideal to do so since the column vectors of a matrix are not generally linearly independent (as is the case for our $A$), and thus they will not form a **basis** of the image.  In order to find a basis, we can take a smallest linearly independent subset of these vectors.

Now, by our previous statements, the image of $EA$ is the span of the vectors
$$
\pmatrix{1\\0\\0},\pmatrix{0\\1\\0},\pmatrix{6\\-3/2\\0}, \pmatrix{6\\-1\\0}
$$
However, in this case, it's clear that we can find a basis of the image of $EA$ by simply taking the vectors corresponding to the pivots.  That is, the image of $EA$ is the span of the  vectors
$$
\pmatrix{1\\0\\0},\pmatrix{0\\1\\0}
$$
Which are, in fact, linearly independent.  What this means then is that for any vector $x$, we have
$$
EAx = a\pmatrix{1\\0\\0} + b\pmatrix{0\\1\\0} = \pmatrix{a\\b\\0}
$$
For some choice of $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$. Now, note that
$$
\pmatrix{1\\0\\0} 
= EA\cdot \pmatrix{1\\0\\0\\0} 
= E\left(A\cdot \pmatrix{1\\0\\0\\0}\right)
= E \cdot \pmatrix{1\\1\\2}\\
\pmatrix{0\\1\\0} 
= EA\cdot \pmatrix{0\\1\\0\\0} 
= E\left(A\cdot \pmatrix{0\\1\\0\\0}\right)
= E \cdot \pmatrix{2\\4\\2}
$$
It follows that
$$
Ax = E^{-1}(EAx) = E^{-1}\cdot \left(a\pmatrix{1\\0\\0} + b\pmatrix{0\\1\\0}\right) 
= a\pmatrix{1\\1\\2} + b\pmatrix{2\\4\\2}
$$
So that these two vectors form a basis of the image, as desired.

Comment: Very nice explanation. Can you elaborate on why the span of columns that corresponds to the pivots are the image ?

Comment: I've added something at the end.  Hopefully that clears things up.

Answer (score 1):

Think of what you did as the coefficients' matrix of a homogeneous system with four variable $\;x_i\;,\;i=1,2,3,4\;$ in order to find the kernel, so what you're said there is:

$$\text{Second row:}\;\;x_2-\frac32x_3-x_4=0\iff 2x_2=3x_3+2x_4\\
\text{First row:}\;\;x_1+6x_3+6x_4=0\implies x_1=-6x_3-6x_4$$

and you have two *free* variables $\;x_3,x_4\;$ (and thus its dimension's two), so a basis for the kernel is

$$\left\{\;x_3=1\,,\,x_4=0\implies\begin{pmatrix}\!\!-6\\3\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}\;\;,\;\;x_3=0\,,\,x_4=1\implies\begin{pmatrix}\!\!-6\\2\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}\;\right\}$$

Do now something similar with the original matrix's columns, and take into account that in this case $\;\dim\text{Im}\,T=2\;$ (why?)